# Sumifs vba loop in every row

Tags: excel, vba

i am trying to do a macro that does a sumifs based on one condition where the condition is set by the value of the first cell of each row. Table 2 is the result I want. What it looks like in Excel=Sumifs(Sales;Store;nStore;Retailer;nRetailer)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzqvS.png)

Comment: Why don't use the already existing function SUMIF?

Comment: You could use consolidation method.

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary builds a fast SUMIF and constructs a unique list of retailers along the way.

```
Sub mySumIf()

    Dim i As Long, arr As Variant, retailer As string, dict As Object

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    dict.comparemode = vbTextCompare

    With Worksheets("tab 1")
        'collect source values into array
        arr = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)).Value2
    End With

    retailer = UCase(Worksheets("tab 2").Cells(4, "F").Value2)

    'build a dictionary with Stores as keys and Sales as Items
    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        If UCase(arr(i, 2)) = retailer Then
            dict.iktem(arr(i, 1)) = dict.iktem(arr(i, 1)) + arr(i, 3)
        End If
    Next i

    With Worksheets("tab 2")
        'put Stores and Summed Sales onto target worksheet
        .Cells(6, "E").Resize(dict.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(dict.keys)
        .Cells(6, "F").Resize(dict.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the Consolidate method:

**Steps:**

1. Select the cell you want to insert total (In my scenario cell D1)
2. Go to **Data** - **Data Tools** - **Consolidate**
3. Select the whole range (**A1:B9**) of data at **References**
4. Press **Add**
5. Press **OK**

**Results:**

[image]